# PHP cURL request failing to balanced payments

Tags: php, curl, balanced-payments

I'm trying to submit a cURL request to [Balanced Payment's](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/overview) test marketplace to simulate charging a credit card but I keep on getting an "unauthorized" status with "authentication-required" as the category_code. I've been able to successfully submit other requests using their documentation, so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm following [these steps](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/overview#charge-a-credit-card) to charge a credit card in the test marketplace.

I'm only at step 1 which is to create an account to associate the card token with which is referred to as the URI.

```
//all of these parameters are supplied in the documentation

$url = 'https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP3k9AuX9cW549vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts';
$post_arr[] = 'username=6d2896e8e9a911e2b3cd02xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:';
$post_arr[] = 'card_uri=/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/cards/CC3DSm7qtThxh6DRe6lnYNVC';
$post = implode('&',$post_arr);

//make the request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); // 3 seconds to connect
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // 10 seconds to complete
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
```

This is the output

```
{ "status": "Unauthorized", "category_code": "authentication-required", "category_type": "permission", "_uris": {}, "description": "Not permitted to perform show on cards. Your request id is OHMefab3f08ea6711e2950a026ba7xxxxxxxxxxxxx.", "request_id": "OHMefab3f08ea6711e2950a026baxxxxxxxxxxxx", "status_code": 401 }
```

However, I when I make the request with the following parameters to [tokenize a card](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html#tokenize-a-card), it works.

```
$url = 'https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP3k9AuX9cW549vxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cards';
$post_arr[] = '6d2896e8e9a911e2b3cd026bxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:';
$post_arr[] = 'expiration_month=12';
$post_arr[] = 'security_code=123';
$post_arr[] = 'card_number=5105105105105100';
$post_arr[] = 'expiration_year=2020';
$post_arr[] = 'category_type=request';
$post = implode('&',$post_arr);
```

Here is the output

```
{ "security_code_check": "true", "_type": "card", "hash": "b7250dd4b4827a88d5e4132b67f02916bce6f8e83d4ca0d779d1351b360ff6af", "brand": "MasterCard", "expiration_month": 12, "_uris": {}, "meta": {}, "last_four": "5100", "id": "CCSBORr685LWzmR62FSKZaw", "customer": null, "account": null, "postal_code_check": "true", "name": "None", "expiration_year": 2020, "created_at": "2013-07-11T21:01:53.245948Z", "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP3k9AuX9cW549vd1Ao5M0OW/cards/CCSBORr685LWzmR62FSKZaw", "card_type": "mastercard", "is_valid": true, "is_verified": true }
```

**edit - I could still be doing something incorrectly, but I think there may be a mistake in the documentation**

I removed the 'card_uri' parameter from my request and it succeeded. Upon checking out the returned JSON I noticed that it's 'cards_uri' not 'card_uri'. Maybe I'm still not doing something correctly, but when I changed my initial request to 'cards_uri' it then succeeded.

Here is the output now

```
{ "_type": "account", "_uris": { "holds_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "holds" }, "bank_accounts_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "bank_accounts" }, "refunds_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "refunds" }, "customer_uri": { "_type": "customer", "key": "customer" }, "debits_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "debits" }, "transactions_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "transactions" }, "credits_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "credits" }, "cards_uri": { "_type": "page", "key": "cards" } }, "bank_accounts_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/bank_accounts", "meta": {}, "transactions_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/transactions", "email_address": null, "id": "AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk", "credits_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/credits", "cards_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/cards", "holds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/holds", "name": null, "roles": [], "created_at": "2013-07-11T21:24:55.567233Z", "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk", "refunds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/refunds", "customer_uri": "/v1/customers/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk", "debits_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP24GBSQWq3M2nzdEtvvnHOf/accounts/AC2A9aCbuzUWalMNX7JXbhrk/debits" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not authenticating.  Try adding

```
curl_setopt('6d2896e8e9a911e2b3cd026ba7f8ec28:', CURLOPT_USERPWD)
```

Comment: I got it to work by simply changing 'card_uri' to 'cards_uri'. My edit at the bottom shows some details. I tried your method as well but it threw an error stating " A non well formed numeric value encountered" in reference to that line.